# how to fix Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet'. An explicit conversion exists

Tags: c#, selenium, automation

Below is the code I am using:

```
public string ExcelSetup(int x, int y)
{
    excel.Application Xapp = new excel.Application();
    excel.Workbook Xworkbook = Xapp.Workbooks.Open("E:\\Selenium needs\\SearchDataFile");
    excel._Worksheet Xworksheet = Xworkbook.Sheets[1];
    excel.Range Xrange = Xworksheet.UsedRange;
    return Xrange.Cells[x][y].value2;
}
```

Error stack trace as below:

> Error CS0266  Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to
>   'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet'. An explicit conversion
>   exists (are you missing a
>   cast?)    omarclass   C:\Users\ihab\source\repos\omarclass\omarclass\Class1.cs    17      Active

Answer (score 1):

You need to explicitly cast your type.

```
excel._Worksheet Xworksheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)Xworkbook.Sheets[1];
```

Comment: that seems work but when i continue the code like this i'm getting another error

Comment: excel.Application Xapp = new excel.Application();
            excel.Workbook Xworkbook = Xapp.Workbooks.Open("H:\\selen\\email");

            excel._Worksheet Xworksheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)Xworkbook.Sheets[1];

            excel.Range Xrange = Xworksheet.UsedRange;
            return Xrange.Cells[x][y].value;

Comment: Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'object' omarclass